# Tracing Request Content Issued By Visual Studio Generated Web Service Proxy

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have a web reference proxy built up by the "Add Web Reference" feature in Visual Studio and need to trace/see the actual content it's posting to the remote web server. Can someone please tell me how I can do? Thanks!

Comment: James? Still care about this? If so, please say why not Fiddler so someone can find you the second best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trace web service request and response details you can add the below configuration in web.config.

```
<!-- Tracing Request/Response -->

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
            <listeners>
                <add name="AsmxTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="REQ_RES.log" />
                <!--traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId"-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>


<!-- Tracing Request/Response -->
```

by adding this, for every request and response the log will be created in your root folder with the name of 'REQ_RES.log'